# How to add properties to object incrementally?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to map object where correct ID will contain the array that belongs to it.

Here is the scenario:

```
let obj = {}
const arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < someIds.length; i++) {
  const res = await someApiCall() // returns array
 
 obj = {
    id: someIds[i],
    res
  }

 arr.push(obj)

 return arr

}
```

The thing here is that `arr` will only output last set of object because of iterating over the values.

For example I get

```
[{id: 122, res: "whatever122"}]
```

where I want to get

```
[{id: 122, res: "whatever122"}, {id: 111, res: "whatever111"}, {id: 133, res: "whatever133}]
```

How do I concatenate all?

Comment: Move your `return` out of `for` loop?.. Now you return after 1st iteration.

Comment: There isn't any trace of TypeScript in this question.

Answer (score 2):

You return `arr` to fast. It should be returned outside the `for` scope:

```
let obj = {}
const arr = []

for (let i = 0; i < someIds.length; i++) {
  const res = await someApiCall() // returns array
 
  obj = {
    id: someIds[i],
    res
   }

   arr.push(obj)
 }

 return arr
```

Comment: Silly me! Thanks... can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Move the return statement outside of the for loop, which would wait for all of the objects to get added to the array.

```js
let obj = {}
const arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < someArr.length; i++) {
    const res = await someApiCall() // returns array
    obj = {
        id: res[i],
        res
    }
    arr.push(obj)
}
return arr
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is produced by the `return` statement that should probably stay outside the `for` loop. It completes the execution of the current function and returns (an optional value) to the caller.

A simpler way to write what you need is to use `Promise.all()` to run all the calls to `someApiCall()` in parallel (if they are independent). This way the code run much faster:

```js
async function doSomething() {
  return await Promise.all(
    someIds.map(
      async (id) => {
        return {
          id: id,
          res: await someApiCall(id),
        };
      }
    )
  );
}
```

### How it works

`someIds.map()` calls the callback function that it receives as argument for each item of `someIds` and returns a new array that contains the values returned by the callback function.

Because the callback function is asynchronous and uses `await`, it returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) as soon as the `await`-ed call starts, without waiting it to complete.

The array of promises returned by `someIds.map()` is passed as argument to [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) that waits for all of them and returns an array containing the values returned by the promises (which are the objects returned by the callback were they be synchronous).

#### Remark

The `await` in front of `Promise.all()` is not really needed. Without it, the function `doSomething()` returns the promise returned by `Promise.all()`. With it, the function returns an array of objects. Either way, the call of `doSomething()` still needs to be `await`-ed and the value produced by it after `await` is an array of objects.

Comment: Don't `return await`. It's the same silly thing like `promise.then(value => value)`

Comment: You are right in this example. The things are different if the code is like `try { return await doIt(); } catch (err) { ... }`.
And, as I mentioned in the answer, that `return` changes the type of the returned value (and the value itself). This matters in TypeScript and it also matters if the caller needs to process the returned data (in this case an `await` must be present either in `doSomething()` or in its caller) or it further returns the value (a promise or the actual data) unprocessed to its caller.